# How to merge csv files into single parquet file inside a folder in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, merge, apache-spark-sql

I want to merge three csv files into single parquet file using pyspark.

**Below mentioned is my S3 path,10th date folder having three files, I want merge those files into a single file as parquet**

```
"s3://lla.raw.dev/data/shared/sap/orders/2022/09/10/orders1.csv,orders2.csv,orders3.csv"
```

**Single file**

```
"s3://lla.raw.dev/data/shared/sap/orders/parquet file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read from CSVs and write to parquet

```
(spark
    # read from CSV
    .read.csv('s3://lla.raw.dev/data/shared/sap/orders/2022/09/10/')
    
    # turn to single file
    .coalesce(1)
 
    # write to parquet
    .write
    .parquet('s3://lla.raw.dev/data/shared/sap/orders/parquet')
)
```